# What's the strength of logic without $\neg\neg\exists x P(x) \implies \exists x P(x)$?

Tags: logic, soft-question, formal-proofs, constructive-mathematics

As far as I understand, the main idea of constructive logic is that we only allow proof methods that let us show the statement $\exists x:P(x)$ only by *constructing* an explicit such object $x$, right? So for instance one can't do this:

> first assume that $\exists x: P(x)$ is *false*, then this leads to …, which is a contradiction; therefore $\exists x: P(x)$.

Having this main idea of constructive logic in mind I would define constructive logic (= intuitionistic logic?) to be logic without the rule $\neg\neg\exists x P(x)\implies\exists xP(x)$. But this seems to contradict the slogan "constructive logic is classical logic without law of excluded middle (and therefore – because these two happen to be equivalent – without double negation elimination)". I'm assuming this is the "correct" definition of constructive logic. So constructive logic is classical logic without $\neg\neg A\implies A$.

My question is already in the title: *How strong is classical logic without $\neg\neg\exists x P(x)\implies\exists xP(x)$?* Is it strictly stronger than constructive logic; and is it strictly weaker than classical logic?

Another question I have is this (but it's quite "soft"): Why does one define constructive logic as the logic without $\neg\neg A\implies A$ rather than logic without $\neg\neg\exists x P(x)\implies\exists xP(x)$? Isn't using the rule $\neg\neg A\implies A$ for an *existential* $A$ what makes a proof *non*-constructive?

Comment: To prove $\lnot \lnot \exists x Px \Rightarrow \exists x Px$ you need double negation...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: To prove what? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: [Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) rejects *DN* (that is equiv to *LEM*) precisely because he does not agree on the fact that in order to assert the existence of "some $x$ that is $P$" it is enough to prove the absurdity of "there is no $x$ that is $P$".

Comment: You seem to be asking what kind of logic we get if *instead* of disallowing the double negation schema $\lnot\lnot A\implies A$, where $A$ ranges over any closed formula, we only disallow that implication when $A$ has the specific form $\exists xP(x)$. But in that case, we could still take $A$ to be $(\exists xP(x))\lor(Q\land\lnot Q)$ for some propositional formula $Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments section, in "logic without $¬¬∃xP(x) ⟹ ∃xP(x)$" the statement "$¬¬A ⟹ A$" where $A$ is $(∃xP(x))∨(Q∧¬Q)$ ($Q$ can be any statement, such as $∃x.x=x$) is still true. Now if $¬¬∃xP(x)$ then $¬¬((∃xP(x))∨(Q∧¬Q))$; because if $¬((∃xP(x))∨(Q∧¬Q))$, then $¬(∃xP(x))$. Also, if $(∃xP(x))∨(Q∧¬Q)$, then by case analysis $∃xP(x)$.

Thus we have proven in "logic without $¬¬∃xP(x) ⟹ ∃xP(x)$" that $¬¬∃xP(x) ⟹ ∃xP(x)$. Therefore, this logic is equivalent to classical logic.

Answer (score 1):

Classical logic including proofs by contradiction can be mapped to a subset of constructive logic while preserving consistency: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#TraClaIntLog

Therefore, one might consider constructive logic as being "stronger" when it comes to expressiveness. After all, it can, in addition to providing support for classical logic, express statements which cannon be expressed in classical logic.